# Why does PowerPoint Animation show up before animation?

Tags: microsoft-powerpoint

I am using PowerPoint 2013 on a Windows 8 work station.

I am using Animation in my presentation. I am having text animate from the right to left on the PowerPoint screen.

My problem is, when I run the animate preview the text is already there and then the animation (from right to left) starts.

What do I have to do to make sure the text does not show up before the text animates from right to left?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

What you are using is a "motion" animation, so it only moves the existing object on your slide. You have to add an extra animation (an entrance animation) to your text.

You can add an extra animation using the following button, under `Animation` tab:

[image]

Make sure that the entrance animation is above the motion animation in the animation pane.